# States $-|0\rangle$ and $i|0\rangle$ in Bloch Sphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-states, bloch-sphere

I am new on quantum computing and starting reading a book about it. Going through it, the Bloch sphere was described for two states.

My question about is: where are the states $-|0\rangle$ and $i|0\rangle$ represented in the sphere?

Comment: Which book, page etc.? Additionally, consider to use \langle and \rangle instead of $<$ and $>$ for bra-kets. I've changed that now. However, feel free to undo the edit if you prefer the other notation.

Comment: They are the same phsical state. Rememeber that *states* correspond to rays in Hilbert space, rather than to vectors.

Comment: @mikestone They are not the same physical states. The Bloch sphere captures only single-qubit information. The phase matters when other degrees of freedom are present and the Bloch sphere simply cannot describe that.

Comment: @DanielSank If the state is written as it is, the phase does not matter. The phase matters in superposition, but then it does not make sense to talk about |0>. Phase *changes* matter.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch sure, and I suspect the underlying confusion here is that the Bloch sphere simply cannot represent the state of a qubit when there are other degrees of freedom in the system.

Comment: I doubt that the origin of the question has any relation to having more than one qubit. Certainly, the answer to the actual question is clear: They are the same point. (And, beyond that, they describe the same physical state.)

Comment: @JasonFunderberker - the book is "Quantum Computing: An applied Approach", page 33 - and thanks for correcting the format of the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general superposition state $|\psi\rangle$ of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ can be written as $$|\psi\rangle = \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)|0\rangle+\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)e^{i\phi}|1\rangle$$ for $\;0\leq \theta \leq \pi$ and $0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi$ uniquely up to an overall phase. Therefore, if we take $\phi$ and $\theta$ to be the polar and azimuthal angles of a unit sphere respectively, every $|\psi\rangle$ can be written as a point on this unit sphere.

$|0\rangle$ multiplied by any phase is therefore in the same position as $|0\rangle$. We have this "up to an overall phase" condition since the global phase factor has no physical meaning, not changing the expectation values of any Hermitian operator.

Answer (score 2):

$\renewcommand{\ket}[1]{\left \lvert #1 \right \rangle}$
Both $\ket{0}$ and $i \ket{0}$ are at the north pole of the Bloch sphere.

### The Bloch sphere only works for a single qubit

If the qubit is the *only* thing in the system, then the phase cannot be measured and those two states are effectively the same.
The Bloch sphere, which only works for single qubits in isolation, reflects that by failing to represent the phase geometrically on the sphere.

### The phase matters when there are multiple qubits

However, the phase matters when there are other degrees of freedom, e.g. other qubits, in the system.

Suppose we take a single qubit and rotate it about the x-axis by angle $\theta$.
Mathematically, that operation is represented as
\begin{align}
\exp(i \theta \sigma_x / 2) \ket{0}
&= \left( \cos(\theta / 2) \mathbb{I} + i \sin(\theta / 2) \sigma_x \right) \ket{0} \\
&= \cos(\theta / 2) \ket{0} + i \sin(\theta / 2) \ket{1} \, .
\end{align}
Note that when $\theta = \pi$ the resulting state is $i \ket{1}$, i.e. we get a rotation of angle $\pi$ around the Bloch sphere (plus an $i$ phase factor!).
That's why we put the factor of 2 in the exponent, i.e. to make the angle $\theta$ correspond to rotation angle in the Bloch sphere representation.

Now consider what happens when $\theta = 2\pi$.
It looks like we just get $\ket{0} \rightarrow - \ket{0}$, which according to the Bloch sphere representation means that we have exactly the same state that we started with.
That *seems* sensible because rotating by $2\pi$ around a sphere takes you right back where you started.
However, what if we make that rotation conditional on the state of another qubit?
For example, we only do that rotation if the other qubit (which is the first qubit in the following equation) is in $\ket{1}$.
Then, for example we'd get a process like this
$$\ket{00} + \ket{10} \rightarrow \ket{00} - \ket{10} \, .$$
Those are different states.

So you can see that while the global phase of a quantum doesn't contain any information, a process that you might think produces a global phase, because it sends a qubit on a complete trip around the Bloch sphere, arriving right back where it started, can produce a meaningful phase if there are other qubits around.